# How to use OpenUI5 in Angular 2 and webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, sapui5

I am unable to add OpenUI5(resources/sap-ui-core.js) [as external library](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f1f4536f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) in angular project. How to use function in ts file? This might [help](http://openui5.org/getstarted.html#step1). I tried to add lines in angular-cli.json:

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
    "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
      "../src/assets/openui5/sap-ui-core.js"
  ],
```

but I don;t know how to use it in ts file for method calls.

Comment: Why would you want to combine them?

Comment: I already have UI written in angular 2 and now it should be hosted on SAP cloud foundry. Roles and login  have been already made manually on cloud foundry. So I need to use functions sap-ui-core.js for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Since UI5 is in bundle and loaded on the page, it should be possible to access it via global variable "sap" like this:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getTheme()
```